# How can I wear small disposable gloves on a medium size hand?

Tags: food, efficiency

I bought the wrong-sized disposable gloves for the kitchen. They are a lot and I do not want to throw them away without knowing if there is any way I can get them on my hands without tearing them apart.

Is there a way or hack to get them on easily?

Comment: You can't. Donate them to charity to feel better, and buy the correct size.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I do that but Charity don't take items that are opened

Comment: That's weird to hear, as they take used clothes. And it's not like you're giving them used gloves, it's easy to see they were never used. Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a tough one. Use this situation to learn for the future :)

If the gloves are really too small, there is nothing you can do. Donate them to someone with smaller hands.

If the gloves are just slightly smaller, then you might have a chance to use them. The most important thing is to make sure that your hands are really dry before using the gloves, and the gloves are really dry inside (normally, they are already dry when they are new, but the ones you you removed are probably wet already). Carefully wear the gloves, finger by finger, without using excessive force. Good luck!

Anyway, another trick for drying your hands is to use talcum powder (baby powder) after drying your hands - to make them extra-dry.

---

I am in a similar situation myself, I succeeded to wear most of them already without using baby powder. Now I have reusable gloves, slightly too big - just to be sure :D

Answer (score -1):

That's an unusual request, but one approach would be to fill the too-small glove with water, over a basin for obvious reasons and once extended, carefully force your hand into the glove. Your hand will displace the water, stretching the glove even more, but if a release path is provided and *the glove has sufficient stretch remaining*, you may succeed.

I had originally considered to suggest to inflate the glove, but that is fairly impractical. A means of creating a vacuum around the outside of the glove would create a similar circumstance, but that's certainly not going to be a household hack.

Comment: Mummifying the hands with tana leaf tea can shrink them considerably: https://www.healingwell.com/community/default.aspx?f=35&m=2845740, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mummy's_Hand.